# Javascript not giving the desired output

Tags: javascript, split

What is the difference between `split(' ')` and the same `split(" ")`.. Is there anything that the second type of split is supported in ie8?

Comment: They should be the same. Is it possible that upstream somewhere you've nested this call in a set of quotes(or doublequotes) that's breaking the literal?

Answer (score 2):

No difference, `" "` and `' '` are two different way to write the same string literal and the function shouldn't be able to discover which one was used.

Could you reproduce a situation where they would behave differently? Can you post a minimum snippet on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I have used a split('#') to redirect in an url this works fine in firefox, chrome and safari but it doesn't work on ie8

Answer (score 0):

A difference could occur with nested quotes, e.g. in an onlick assignment. The rule is double quotes may contain single quotes and vice versa.

```
<button onlick="parts=s.split(' ');">split</button>
```

or

```
<button onlick='parts=s.split(" ");'>split</button>
```